# Trying to figure out why I keep getting prompted to Login into Azure with this code

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

```
$File = 'c:\azure\azradmpwd.txt'
$ash = Get-Content -Path $File | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$ashSvcCred = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('test@test',$ash)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $ashSvcCred

Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId '<subscription code here>'

$rg = '<resource group here>'
$adla = '<azure analytics name here>'

$myrootdir = "/Test/"
$source = "adl://<adl name>.azuredatalakestore.net" + $myrootdir
$dest = "adl://<adl name>.azuredatalakestore.net" + $myrootdir + "Test/"

write-host "$source"
write-host "$dest"

& C:\AdlCopy\AdlCopy.exe /source $source /dest $dest /account $ashSvcCred
```

I'm getting prompted to login to Azure on the last step although I'm already logged in the first few steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Login-AzureRmAccount` is authenticates you for PowerShell context and `AdlCopy.exe` is a separate appplication with its own context.

As we see from [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob), `/Account` option is informative to choose an account for the job but it is not related to authentication, so you will be prompted.

Comment: Any way to pass this information to the AdlCopy.exe.  I'm sorry I'm new to all this.

Comment: @FELIXA Sorry, but I do not see any option for this, AdlCopy is interactive tool and, as I see, can not be runned silently. Follow this feedback post (or create another) : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13035984-tool-like-azcopy-but-for-data-lake . With PowerShell you can download and upload your files : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell but it is not a solution for large amount of data

Comment: I see what you guys mean. Thanks for the input!